# recuperar o id de registro na tabela

Tags: php

não tenho ideia de como recuperar o ´id´ da minha tabela sem passar ele pelo form

tenho o seguinte form

**NOTICIAS**

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="input">
        <label>nome<strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="nome"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
        <label>tags<strong>*</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="tags"/>
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
        <input type="hidden" name="postar" value="postou"/>
        <input type="submit" value="próximo passo"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['postar'])&&$_POST['postar']=='postou'){
    var_dump($_POST);
    //verifico se a noticia ja foi postada
    $vDup=$conn->prepare("SELECT id,nome FROM `noticias` WHERE `nome` = '".$_POST['nome']."'");

    $vDup->execute();

    $count=$vDup->rowCount($_POST['nome']);

    if($count>=1){
        echo "<span class='msg erro'>Essa notícia já foi publicada.</span>";
    }else{
        if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
            echo "O nome da notícia não pode ficar vazia.";
        }else{

            //modificação
            $pID=$vDup->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            foreach($pID AS $listID){
            $id=$listID->id;

            $id=$id;

            $nome=trim($_POST['nome']);
            $slug=$_POST['nome'];
            $tags=trim($_POST['tags']);

            $insertNoticia=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `noticias` (nome,slug,tags) VALUES ('$nome','$slug','$tags')");

            $insertNoticia->execute();

            if($insertNoticia){
                //preciso recuperar o id da minha notícia nessa url
                header("refresh: 3;painel.php?p=escrever-noticia&chave=".$_SESSION['id']."&autor=".$_SESSION['login']."&slug=".$slug."&id=".$id."");
                echo "<span class='msg sucesso'>Processando, aguarde...</span>";
            }else{
                echo "<span class='msg erro'>Erro ao postar essa notícia.</span>";
            }
          }//fecha o foreach
        }
    }
}
```

> http://www.meupainel.com/painel.php?p=escrever-noticia&chave=2&autor=admin&slug=noticia-teste&id=1

meu problema esta em recuperar esse ´id´, como eu não passo via post nem get, não sei como recuperar ele, essa outra página que o form manda quando a noticia e postada, se refere a outra tabela, oque eu preciso e recuperar o ´id´ da tabela noticias, pra fazer ligação entre as duas

Comment: Traz o ID junto no seu SELECT da tabela noticias.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti editei a pergunta com oque voce falou, porem agora nao esta cadastrando nem dando nenhum erro, mais a logica e essa mesmo que vc falou, porem estou errando em alguma coisa

Comment: você tem varias opções, como session `$_SESSION`, ou pode também passa o id pelo html: exemplo: `<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="3487">`

Comment: @Mayron Da um `var_dump` no retorno da seu select para ver o que esta vindo.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo como assim pegar por ´$_SESSION´ a ´$_SESSION´ que eu uso e do meu login, esse jeito ´<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="3487">´ nao entendi como funciona

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti editei a pergunta com o ´var_dump´ mesmo assim nao retorna nada, outra coisa, aquele SELECT eu uso pra saber se a noticia ja foi postada, sera que pode ser esse o problema que nao esta puxando o id? `SELECT id, nome FROM noticias WHERE nome` = '".$_POST['nome']."'` repare que o WHERE  so puxa se for correspondente ao nome certo

Comment: @Mayron roda o `var_dump($_POST);` logo na primeira linha antes dessa validação de postar, e posta o resultado.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo ´array(8) { ["nome"]=> string(1) "teste" ["tags"]=> string(5) "tag 1"  ["postar"]=> string(6) "postou" }´

Comment: @Mayron agora coloca esse vara_sump dentro do if  só para vermos se ele está entrando dentro dele.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo esta entrando sim, retornou a mesma coisa

Comment: @Bulfaitelo eu acho que o problema e aquele SELECT, porque ele so vai executar se estiver alguma noticia com o mesmo nome que eu postar, sera que seria melhor eu fazer outro SELECT? porem e estranho ele nao estar cadastrando a noticia

Comment: @Mayron qual é o resultado do select roda um `var_dump($vDup->execute());` e me fala o retorno

Comment: @Bulfaitelo deu isso bool(true)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86987/discussion-between-bulfaitelo-and-mayron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verificando seu código você está reescrevendo o id, que que pegar, mas como ele ainda não existe, o correto seria inserir no banco para assim pegar o id do ultimo cadastro.

```
if(isset($_POST['postar'])&&$_POST['postar']=='postou'){
    var_dump($_POST);
    //verifico se a noticia ja foi postada
    $vDup=$conn->prepare("SELECT id,nome FROM `noticias` WHERE `nome` = '".$_POST['nome']."'");

    $vDup->execute();

    $count=$vDup->rowCount();

    if($count>=1){
        echo "<span class='msg erro'>Essa notícia já foi publicada.</span>";
    }else{
        if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
            echo "O nome da notícia não pode ficar vazia.";
        }else{

            $nome=trim($_POST['nome']);
            $slug=$_POST['nome'];
            $tags=trim($_POST['tags']);

            $insertNoticia=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `noticias` (nome,slug,tags) VALUES ('$nome','$slug','$tags')");

            $insertNoticia->execute();
            $id = $conn->lastInsertId();
            if($insertNoticia){
                //preciso recuperar o id da minha notícia nessa url
                header("refresh: 3;painel.php?p=escrever-noticia&chave=".$_SESSION['id']."&autor=".$_SESSION['login']."&slug=".$slug."&id=".$id."");
                echo "<span class='msg sucesso'>Processando, aguarde...</span>";
            }else{
                echo "<span class='msg erro'>Erro ao postar essa notícia.</span>";
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

removi o foreach, e adicionei o lastInsertId() para pegar o ultimo id inserido no banco de dados.